# Как сделать удаление инлайн клавиатуры после нажатия?

Tags: python, telegram, бот

**@searchIT_bookbot** - пример. Когда нажал на кнопку, то старая клавиатура удаляется и появляется новая. У нее новый текст сверху и кнопки.

*Библиотека - pytelegrambotapi, язык - пайтон*

Сначала я использовал **edit_message_reply_markup**, но там нельзя поменять текст над кнопками

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update.message.reply_text(text=f"some text", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),)
```

попробуйте это.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать параметр клавиатуры `one_time_keyboard=True`

Это может не помочь если у вас кастомная клавиатура, тогда я написал такой костыль

```
# объявляем пустую клавиатуру в начале файла как константу
hideBoard = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove() 

# потом, когда надо убрать клавиатуру:
def process_fullname_step(message, phone):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    msg = bot.send_message(
      chat_id, 
      "Отлично! Теперь напиши имя и фамилию. ✍️", 
      reply_markup=hideBoard # И передаем сюда созданную выше клавиатуру
    )
```

https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.replykeyboardmarkup.html#telegram.ReplyKeyboardMarkup.one_time_keyboard